# How to resume mapping a list if one fails RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

Given the following code, the onErrorResumeNext method will just replace an errored item in the list with "hi". How would I go about getting it to continue on with iterating through the rest of the list?

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add(new Testo());
list.add("two");
list.add("three");    

Observable.fromIterable(list)
    .map(item -> item.toString())
    .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just("hi"))
    .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item), onError -> System.out.println("error"));

private static class Testo {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an inner reactive stream, so the outer won't be terminated when error occures:

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
    .flatMap((item) -> Observable.just(item)
        .map(_item -> _item.toString())
        .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.just("hi")))
    .subscribe(item -> System.out.println(item), onError -> System.out.println("error"));
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference

Comment: In RxJava an error is a terminal event that terminates the reactive stream and no other events should be emitted after a terminal event. Because of this the original implementation doesn't work as intended (it stops working as soon as an error occurs). And to fix that what you need to do is to use another inner stream which will of course be terminated upon error, but since we use onErrorResumeNext() the outer stream won't get the error (it will get the value you put in onErrorResumeNext()) thus it won't be terminated and will continue working.

Comment: What if I want a conditional stream if lets say for eg out of 10 if 4th fail I want to continue and if 6th fails I want to stop the stream completely?

Comment: You can do something like this - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators#onerrorreturn

Inside onErrorReturn() lambda you can check how many events were emitted and then do whatever you want.